# Linear Algebra Textbook for Reference?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, online-resources

Just want a good linear algebra textbook for reference. 
I know that there is a lot of good ones, but I am not a mathematician and I don't want anything way too abstract like Axler, Curtis, Hoffman&Kunze, etc.

However, I want the text to cover "advanced" things like inner product, Jordan forms, Bilinear forms, etc, and at least prove some of the theorems.

I am currently trying Blyth& Robertson. Though I prefer a book with examples and exercises more interesting. Also LADW is good, though I prefer paperback.

Any other suggestions?

Edit: Not that I cannot understand Axler...

Due my limited exposure to algebra and laziness, I find it way harder to see the connection between LADR and first-year linear algebra than between, say, Rudin and calculus (You just want to replace "compact set" with "closed intervals" most of the time...right?). That's why I think LADW is better for me, even if many people think it is harder than LADR.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a simple one, try [Schaum's Outline of Linear Algebra](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Schaum_s_Outline_of_Linear_Algebra_5th_E.html?id=o7U2JI5gnkAC&redir_esc=y). It does cover inner products, Jordan canonical forms and bilinear forms.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you either [Linear Algebra - Serge Lang](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387964126) or [Linear Algebra - Shilov](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048663518X)

Comment: If the OP thinks Axler's is already too abstract, I personally don't think Lang's is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

This book is great : Linear Algebra and Its Applications, David C. Lay, University of Maryland. https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Lay-Linear-Algebra-and-Its-Applications-4th-Edition/9780321385178.html

Many examples and exercices (even corrected). I know some others, but these are in french.

Answer (score 0):

I love Kuldeep Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step* (2013) for 3 reasons. It provides pictures + [complete solutions to all problems](https://maths-for-all.co.uk/linear-algebra/), and uses color.

See also https://linearalgebras.com/ten-best-linear-algebra-books.html.